# Can´t have operation with the same name?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, interface, datacontract

I generated a WCF webservice interface from a WSDL with SVCutil. Then I created a service.svc file where I Implmenet the interface like this :

```
    public class Service2 : wsEquipmentSoap
{
    public GetEquipmentResponse GetEquipment(GetEquipmentRequest request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<GetEquipmentResponse> GetEquipmentAsync(GetEquipmentRequest request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When browsing this service I get the following Exception :

> Cannot have two operations in the same contract with the same name,
>   methods GetEquipmentAsync and GetEquipment in type wsEquipmentSoap
>   violate this rule. You can change the name of one of the operations by
>   changing the method name or by using the Name property of
>   OperationContractAttribute.

Thay do however not have the same name? one is named GetEquipment and the other GetEquipmentAsync.

I can however see that svcutil have genereated the same Action string in the interface :

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/GetEquipment", ReplyAction="*")]
GetEquipmentResponse GetEquipment(GetEquipmentRequest request);

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/GetEquipment", ReplyAction="*")]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GetEquipmentResponse> GetEquipmentAsync(GetEquipmentRequest request);
```

I dont want to change the interface but I I change the Action and add Async in the end of the Async method I get this exception instead :

> The synchronous OperationContract method 'GetEquipment' in type
>   'wsEquipmentSoap' was matched with the task-based asynchronous
>   OperationContract  method 'GetEquipmentAsync' because they have the
>   same operation name 'GetEquipment'. When a synchronous
>   OperationContract method is matched to a task-based asynchronous
>   OperationContract method, the two OperationContracts must have the
>   same value for the 'Action' property. In this case, the values are
>   different. To fix it, change the 'Action property of one of the
>   OperationContracts to match the other. Alternatively, changing the
>   name of one of the methods will prevent matching.

Even with the explaination I still do not get why these exceptions is thrown? The interface is generated with svcutil and changing in the interface do not feel right?

Comment: You are mapping two different items to the same tag.  Both lines have the following : System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/GetEquipment", ReplyAction="*")

Comment: Yes I do, why did svcutil generated it this way? I tried to change the action to GetEquipmentAsync on one of them but that genereated the synchronouse operationcontract exception above.

Comment: What is in the XML file used by service?